# Get city and country from AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview, location

I use an `AutoCompleteTextView` to get the location that select user.
My problem is that the `AutoCompleteTextView` not always return the same structure.

Example for Valencia Spain return "Valencia, Spain" (City, Country) but for New York return "New York, NY, United States".

Then I need alone city and country but I do not know how to get it, I wonder if there is any api call or the `AutoCompleteTextView` have any option to return me separate the city and the country.

This is my PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter:

```
 @Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new Filter.FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                filterResults.values = PlaceAPI.autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                filterResults.count = resultList.size();
            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            setItems((ArrayList<String>) results.values);
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };

    return filter;
}
```

If any have idea please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found any better solution then kindly please share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each result is a String type. So, try splitting each result into parts by help of split() method of String class. Use "," as the regular expression in the method. This method will return you a String[].

Now, get the number of elements in the String[] and surely the last element will be the country and the rest will be the city (I'm saying this according to the example you gave in your question above). Take the last element as your country and for the city you can then concatenate the remaining elements of the String[] (incase the String[] contains more than 2 element which will be in NewYork according to your example).

Example for concatenation of Strings:

Lets take myStrings as my String[];

```
for(String string : myStrings) {
    if (string.length() > 2) {
        // concatenate your strings here to form the complete city name
    }
}
```

To know ore about splitting Strings, go to the following webpage:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: This is not the best option but found! If you find better option also inform me. Thanks!